# What's the format of a `package-desc` for `package-install`?

Tags: package, documentation, help

The documentation of `package-install` says: "Install the package PKG. PKG can be a package-desc [...]", but then it doesn't explain what is the format of a `package-desc`.

Comment: Take a look at the [definition in `package.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-25.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el#L361).

Comment: Please consider filing an Emacs bug / enhancement request to improve that doc: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Users shouldn't have to look at the source code to understand that, presumably.

Comment: `C-h o package-desc` should describe it (and actually "package-desc" in the above docstring should be surrounded with \`...' so that you can just click on it to get that info).

Comment: @Stefan Yours is an answer.  Please post it as such, so that I can choose it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h o package-desc RET` should describe it (and actually "package-desc" in the above docstring should be surrounded with `...' so that you can just click on it to get that info.  I already fixed it in Emacs's master branch, so don't bother reporting it, tho).